# House of Music + Witch's Hut

Tags: untagged

**House of Music guild card states:**

"Whenever you use the Tavern, you may also capture a monster from the Forest or fight a captured monster."

**Witch's Hut location states:**

"Use the ability at the Location of the King's Guard"

---

So, do I get to capture/fight a monster when using the Witch's Hut, and the King's Guard is at the tavern? I don't know if "use the ability" and "use the location" are synonymous. (Normally' it's irrelevant, because you can't separate the two ideas.)

*[This Q/A](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2491073/guild-house-music-what-means-use) is related, but not the same.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "use the location" is short for "use the ability at the location".

See this usage from the designer's posts [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2505746/article/36305120#36305120) and [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2491073/guild-house-music-what-means-use).

The designer refers to this variously as (emphasis added):

> **using the ability at the location** is optional.

> location **ability may be used**

> You can **use the forest** but decide not to defeat anything

> So when you **activate it** ...

Comment: I’m not getting that from the links you posted (one of which is the one I posted). Can you help me see the wording that ties them together like you’re suggesting?

Comment: @Jessy Sure: I've edited my answer to include the examples I'm basing the answer on.

Comment: Yeah, seems like the same thing. Nice collection of evidence.